# Bad values after adding them to array in JsonCpp module in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, for-loop, jsoncpp

I have got problem after adding values to jsoncpp array. My code is next:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include "jsoncpp/dist/jsoncpp.cpp"
#include "jsoncpp/dist/json/json.h"
#include "jsoncpp/dist/json/json-forwards.h"

using namespace std;

void printArray(const char *measure, float **arr, int rows, int cols)
{

    int i,j;

    cout << endl;

    for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            cout << arr[i][j] << "\t";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
    cout << endl;


    if (measure == "ECG")
    {
        int i,j;

        Json::Value ECG;
        Json::Value time(Json::arrayValue);
        Json::Value values(Json::arrayValue);

        for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (j = 0; j < 1; j++)
            {
                time.append(Json::Value(arr[i][j]));
            }
        }

        for (i = 0; i < rows; i++)
        {
            for (j = 1; j < 2; j++)
            {
                values.append(Json::Value(arr[i][j]));
            }
        }

        cout << endl << time << endl;
        cout << endl << values << endl;

    }
}


int main()
{
    int i,j;
    int rows, cols;
    const char *measur;

    rows = 10;
    cols = 2;

    float **array = new float *[rows];
    for(int i = 0; i < rows; i++)
    {
        array[i] = new float [cols];
        for(int j = 0; j < cols; j++)
        {
            array[i][j]=(i+j)/10.0;
        }
    }

    measur = "ECG";

    printArray(measur, array, rows, cols);    
}
```

After compile and run I have the following out:

```
0   0.1 
0.1 0.2 
0.2 0.3 
0.3 0.4 
0.4 0.5 
0.5 0.6 
0.6 0.7 
0.7 0.8 
0.8 0.9 
0.9 1   


[
    0.0,
    0.10000000149011612,
    0.20000000298023224,
    0.30000001192092896,
    0.40000000596046448,
    0.5,
    0.60000002384185791,
    0.69999998807907104,
    0.80000001192092896,
    0.89999997615814209
]

[
    0.10000000149011612,
    0.20000000298023224,
    0.30000001192092896,
    0.40000000596046448,
    0.5,
    0.60000002384185791,
    0.69999998807907104,
    0.80000001192092896,
    0.89999997615814209,
    1.0
]
```

As you can see, before adding values to json array, everything is ok but after, there is a different values. Now it is a test sample of data but it will be a library that will be getting data from ECG, Pulseoximeter, AirFlow etc. modules from RapsberryPi so data from "values" array will be like 0.14453453, 0.23546456 etc. and I have to prevent situation like that. My values has to be accurate as much as I can get that.

Thanks.

Comment: Strings vs. floating-point representation.  Either store the strings or accept that floats and doubles will not always exactly match the strings.  They will be +/- a small amount.

Answer (score 0):

Floats and doubles do not store base 10 numbers.  The base 2 they use will sometimes be very close but +/- a small value.  Wiki on floating point: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating-point_arithmetic

You can often get back the same values (for display purposes) later by converting the floats back to strings with sprintf or similar.  It looks like you are reading 1 decimal digit so for example:

```
 sprintf(stringout, "%.1f", floatin);
```

When comparing floats and doubles, always keep this "not quite equal" fact in mind.  Instead of asking "is x == y" you should ask "is x == y +/- some tolerance value like 0.0001"

Answer (score 0):

Print your input values with greater precision like this:

```
cout << std::setw(11) << std::setprecision(9) << arr[i][j] << "\t";
```

Everything else works fine.

EDIT: Where is no prevention for that, because you can't represent 0.9 in binary 100% accurately. In binary fraction composed of b1*1/2 + b2*1/4 + b3 * 1/4 + ...
And if you read data from sensors then it's already 0.1212121212.... If you want to show to the user trucated data you can use the same trick as above. But if you still want to use only 10-15 decimal places for storage, then you need to use fixed point math, but i bet you don't.

Comment: Ok, so that trick showed me that even data in my arr is different that it should be. But you can see, that in main function when I am generating "arr" there should be 0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4 etc... So how to get more accurate data? I mean... When I'm creating array there is for example 0.9, but after sending it to the function, there is in the same place 0.89999997615814209. How to prevent that? How to get accuration for a ~10-15 dicimal places? And how to add data from arr to jsoncpp array with for ex. accurate about 8 decimal places?

Comment: ok, I solved that problem just changing array type from float to double. Now I have different problem - how to set digit limitation during appending data to "values" table? My all data will be acurate to 16 decimal places because of "double" and I want to cut excess of digits before or during for-loop.

Comment: @Fempter what excess? you are right, double can store up to 16 decimal digits, so that is maximum number of digits you would have, of course modulo the fact of exponent. If you want to not embarass user with such many digits, then that's not about storage, but UI. You can just format string accordingly with `setprecision`.

Comment: yes, I want to use `setprecision` but in my for loop. I want to use this here:

`time.append(Json::Value(arr[i][j]));`

Because as you can see, my data in `time` and `values` table is not what I want to get. I want to append to `time` table data with precision to 3, but to `values` table with precision to 6. How can I do this?

Comment: @Fempter, that's not so easy to do. I advise you to start new question for it. There are plenty of possibilties to do it, like used fixed point arithmetic or transform double to closest fraction (like 1/3, 1/10, so on), but all of them require considerable amount of effort, even you will use some library you will need to think well how to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I changed floatarray type to double and now I have much better accuration. It's fine for me. Now, please tell me, how to send to "values" table only with 8 decimal places values? I don't want to have in values array data like values = [0.12121212 , 0.21212121] but I want to have only for example like this values = [0.1212, 0.2121]. What I want to do is cut off the excess of information in "values" table while loop. I mean, how to set digit limitation during appending data to "values" table.